# how to retrieve the count of a controller function to an ajax progress bar asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to get a raw count from a `foreach` function inside of a result for an AJAX post response. The issue I am facing is that in my post response, I am receiving the total of all the iterations of the foreach, but not the individuals. The purpose of doing this is to show the progress of the upload by filling a progress bar at each iteration.

Controller:

```
public JsonResult progressFunction(int? SystemGeneralAnnouncementId)
        {

            var systemGeneralAnnouncement = (SystemGeneralAnnouncementId == null) ? null : _uow.SystemGeneralAnnouncementRepository.GetById(SystemGeneralAnnouncementId.Value);
            List<Status> status = new List<Status>();

            if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.Statuses.Length > 0)
            {
                status.AddRange(systemGeneralAnnouncement.Statuses.Split(',').Select(item => (Status) Enum.Parse(typeof (Status), item)));
            }

            var allPocEmailAddresses = new List<InstitutionPointOfContact>();
            var pocEmailAddresses = new List<InstitutionPointOfContact>();

            //retrieve all Point of contact based upon selected statuses per each loop
            var result = new List<InstitutionPointOfContact>();
            foreach (var item in status)
            {
                result = _uow.InstitutionPointOfContactRepository.GetAllByStatus(item).ToList();
                allPocEmailAddresses.AddRange(result);
            }

            // Retrieve the poc email addresses based on the who is intended to receive the email message
            if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(1) All Three POCs"))
            {
                pocEmailAddresses = allPocEmailAddresses;
            }
            else
            {
                if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(2) All POCs"))
                {
                    pocEmailAddresses.AddRange(allPocEmailAddresses.Where(r => r.PointOfContactType == PointOfContactTypes.Primary).ToList());
                }
                if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(3) All Compliance POCs"))
                {
                    pocEmailAddresses.AddRange(allPocEmailAddresses.Where(r => r.PointOfContactType == PointOfContactTypes.Secondary).ToList());
                }
                if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(4) All Authorities"))
                {
                    pocEmailAddresses.AddRange(allPocEmailAddresses.Where(r => r.PointOfContactType == PointOfContactTypes.SigningAuthority).ToList());
                }
                if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(5) All Rate POCs"))
                {
                    pocEmailAddresses.AddRange(allPocEmailAddresses.Where(r => r.PointOfContactType == PointOfContactTypes.TuitionRates).ToList());
                }
                if (systemGeneralAnnouncement.SendToRecipients.Contains("(6) Specified Email Address"))
                {
                    var pocs = new List<InstitutionPointOfContact>();

                    string[] emails = systemGeneralAnnouncement.EmailAddresses.Split(',');

                    foreach (string email in emails)
                    {                      
                        var addPoc = new InstitutionPointOfContact { Email = email };

                        User user = _uow.UserRepository.GetByEmail(email);

                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            addPoc.FirstName = "Not Created Account Yet";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            addPoc.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                            addPoc.LastName = user.LastName;
                        }

                        List<InstitutionPointOfContact> opeidAssociatedToUser =
                            _uow.InstitutionPointOfContactRepository
                                .GetAllPocsByEmail(email)
                                .ToList();


                        if (opeidAssociatedToUser.Count == 0)
                        {
                            addPoc.IDNumber = "N/A";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string[] idArray = idAssociatedToUser
                                .Select(x => x.IDNumber)
                                .ToArray();

                            addPoc.IDNumber = string.Join(",", opeidArray);
                        }
                        pocs.Add(addPoc);
                    }                  
                    pocEmailAddresses.AddRange(pocs);
                }
            }

            ViewBag.UploadProgress = 0;
            // if any poc addresses were found...
            if (pocEmailAddresses.Count > 0)
            {
                string emailBody = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(systemGeneralAnnouncement.EmailBody);

                foreach (InstitutionPointOfContact emailAddress in pocEmailAddresses.Where(x => x.Email != "" && x.Email != null).ToList())
                {

                    string firstName = emailAddress.FirstName == null ? "" : emailAddress.FirstName.Trim();
                    string lastName = emailAddress.LastName == null ? "" : emailAddress.LastName.Trim();
                    string userName = firstName + " " + lastName;

                    //iterative for progress bar
                    ViewBag.UploadProgress++;

                }
            }

            return Json (ViewBag.UploadProgress, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

AJAX:

$

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "progressFunction",
        cache: false,
        cacheControl: "no-cache",
        statusCode: {
            500: function () {
                errorWhileSavingData()
            }
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert()
            GenerateProgressBar(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

My question is, can I retrieve the individual count from the Controller (Viewbag.uploadProgress) in the post function so that I can pass it as a variable count in a progress bar?

Update: For clarity, what I need to do is get the individual count of the foreach (1 ~ n), not the completed count, which is what I am receiving now.

Update 2: SingalR is not really an option in this case, as it would be excessive for such a small process, a desired result would come from a "roll your own"

Comment: Why don't you return the actual number?

Comment: If I am understanding the question correctly, why do I just not return the number as a raw value?

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak The reason I am not returning a raw value, is because the end user will not necessarily understand the upload progress, because it is happening behind the scenes. Essentially we are moving items selected as a meta value (all POC's, compliance, authority) and then passing the database values attached to those values to a scheduled task that is later sent out as an email(once weekly) the reason I am looking to do a progress bar is that this takes 3-5 seconds, and I would like to show them that it is both progressing, and completed.

Comment: For progress bars that provide "real-time" feedback as a loop is iterating, you need a way to relay said feedback without returning a result to the AJAX call. The way I implemented this in one of our projects is via SignalR. For such a short running process, you could probably get away with a simple spinner animation. In our project, the loop takes over 30 seconds to complete, so better feedback was necessary.

Comment: @sleeyuen Thank you very much for that information. I will update, but you're right. SignalR is probably excessive for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, this isn't possible given your current setup. Nice attempt with using the ViewBag, but the ViewBag isn't actually passed between Controller and View until the Action is completed and returns to the View. As I mentioned, SignalR would be one way to approach this, but is overkill for your use case.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification. I am seeing that it is going to just pass me a completed count. Is there any other option for a roll your own method?

Comment: *cough* SignalR :)

Comment: Sorry, that was clear in your first statement. I was under the impression that we were discussing something other than signalr. It looks like we are going to take a different approach, and just put in a loading wheel in an ajax call, but you have been extremely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Cheers. And if you ever want to have a peek at the SignalR way, I'm more than willing to share my implementation - it's pretty bare bones, but still overkill for a 3-5 sec process.

Comment: I would apreciate that very much. I think it would be useful for extensability  to understand how to implement long load reports, for future projects